# sqlite hex(1) returns 31?

Tags: sqlite, function, hex

Why SQLite hex() function returns 31 for hex(1).

For example I do:

```
select hex(1) from mytable;
```

And I get 31 but shouldn't it return 1?

Thanks,
Carlos.

Comment: Code of ASCII '1' is 49. Dec 49 is hex 31. That's what you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because :

> The hex() function interprets its argument as a BLOB and returns a
>   string which is the upper-case hexadecimal rendering of the content of
>   that blob.

The hex() function converts a BLOB value into a hexadecimal text representation. The parameter data is assumed to be a BLOB. ***If it is not a BLOB, it will be converted into one.*** The returned text value will contain two hexadecimal characters for each byte in the BLOB.

Comment: Ok... Is is possible to get Hex(1) = 1 ?

Comment: @QLands The hex() function converts a BLOB value into a hexadecimal text representation ... So it seems not possible...

Comment: Additional internal background: sqlite stores everything as text.

Comment: @QLands: You could easily write your own `my_hex()` UDF that would get you that result.